How to disable enhanced notifications on Android from my app?
I am developing an Android messenger. No, users get AI-generated suggestions on notifications, called enhanced notifications, which I would like to disable because they are not useful and users find them untrustworthy because their messages are analyzed by an AI.
I couldn't find any mention of enhanced notifications in the Android developer documentation (1, 2).
Is it possible for my app to somehow disable them?

These seem to be the only ways to control that behavior:

setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions for smart actions
setAllowGeneratedReplies for smart replies

